# Case With Datepart For Weekday

Tags: sql-server

Any ideas what is wrong with the following code?

I am trying to write a case statement that returns today's date on a Monday else takes the max date from a table if today's date inst a Monday

Thanks

```
SELECT 
CASE [EffectiveDate]
When datepart(weekday,getdate()) = 1  Then cast(getdate() as date)
Else max ([EffectiveDate])
End,
FROM
[ARCDAL01PR].[ArcTimeSeries].[arc_ts_data].[PriceCurveData]
WHERE
[CurveName] = 'G_H_TTF.EUR'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CASE [EffectiveDate]
When datepart(weekday,getdate()) = 2 Then cast(getdate() as date)
Else max ([EffectiveDate])
End,
FROM
[ARCDAL01PR].[ArcTimeSeries].[arc_ts_data].[PriceCurveData]
WHERE
[CurveName] = 'G_H_TTF.EUR
```

Monday should be 2nd day of week. Eventually u can try this if using SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT 
CASE [EffectiveDate]
When weekday(getdate(),2) = 1  Then cast(getdate() as date)
Else max ([EffectiveDate])
End,
FROM
[ARCDAL01PR].[ArcTimeSeries].[arc_ts_data].[PriceCurveData]
WHERE
[CurveName] = 'G_H_TTF.EUR
```

---

Update

```
SELECT 
CASE
When datepart(weekday,getdate()) = 2 Then cast(getdate() as date)
Else max ([EffectiveDate])
End as [EffectiveDate]
FROM
[ARCDAL01PR].[ArcTimeSeries].[arc_ts_data].[PriceCurveData]
WHERE
[CurveName] = 'G_H_TTF.EUR'
```

Comment: You may want to SELECT @@DATEFIRST first to ensure that the local calendar settings have Monday assigned to the expected day.

Comment: Thanks for this. When I try the first bit of code I get the error "Incorrect syntax near '='." Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed. After end there was unnecessary "," :).